# Count sequence selected columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query below, I want sequence result like the value of 'feb' will sum by jan and feb, value of 'mar' will sum by jan, feb and mar,... . Is there any way to get the result like that?

```
select A.location as location
     , count(Case When SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2)='01' Then A.customer_no else null end) as "jan"
     , count(Case When SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2)='02' Then A.customer_no else null end) as "feb"
      ....
     , count(Case When SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2)='12' Then A.customer_no else null end) as "dec"
from table_income A group by A.location;
```

Comment: you can wrap your existing query in a subquery and in the outer query do a `SELECT "jan", "jan" + "feb", ... FROM (your existing query)`

Comment: `SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2)='01'` <<-- are you storing your date in a text field?

Comment: Yes, The value of date store as varchar format "20210707". I'm using substring to get only month value.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a much more effective language when you think in rows rather than columns (normalisation).

For example, having one row per month is much simpler...

```
SELECT
  location,
  SUBSTRING(base_date,5,2)   AS base_month,
  SUM(COUNT(customer_no))
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY location
          ORDER BY SUBSTRING(base_date,5,2)
    )
      AS count_cust
FROM
  table_income
GROUP BY
  location,
  SUBSTRING(base_date,5,2)
```

Side notes:

- If your `base_date` is a string, it shouldn't be, use data-types relevant to the data
- If your `base_date` is a `date` or `timestamp`, you should really use date/timestamp functions, such as `EXTRACT(month FROM base_date)`.

You probably should also account for different years...

```
SELECT
  location,
  DATE_TRUNC('month', base_date)   AS base_month,
  SUM(COUNT(customer_no))
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY location, DATE_TRUNC('year', base_date)
          ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', base_date)
    )
      AS count_cust
FROM
  table_income
GROUP BY
  location,
  DATE_TRUNC('month', base_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```sql
SELECT A.location as location
     , count(Case When SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2) in ('01') Then A.customer_no else null end) as "jan"
     , count(Case When SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2) in ('01','02') Then A.customer_no else null end) as "feb"
      ....
     , count(Case When SUBSTRING(A.base_date,5,2) in ('01','02',...'12') Then A.customer_no else null end) as "dec"
from table_income A group by A.location;
```